# PHP echo performance

Tags: php, performance, echo

Which of these commands will perform the best? Worst? And why?

```
echo 'A: '.$a.' B: '.$b.' C: '.$c;

echo 'A: ', $a, ' B: ', $b, ' C: ', $c;

echo "A: $a B: $b C: $c";
```

Comment: IMHO variant no. 1, but I'm just guessing, there were something about that on `php.net`, also compare of `echo` and `printf`

Comment: `echo()`'s performance differences are **utterly meaningless** in the real world.

Comment: If you want to make your server lighter you should focus your attention to bottlenecks mainly

Comment: @Unicron However, that is hardly a reason for down voting this question.

Comment: @Mikulas I did not downvote this question. What makes you think I did?

Comment: @Unicron Well, since that is the only reason to down vote this questing for, I was referring to you and those who great-comment-ed. I suppose I should've posted the comment without the @.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo 'A: ', $a, ' B: ', $b, ' C: ', $c;
```

will be fastest, because here all parts of a string are directly copied to the output stream, whereas the other variants would involve first concatenation the string parts. "Concatenation" means that for every part of the string a new chunk of memory must be allocated and the previous string copied into it.

I will illustrate it with the following example

```
echo 'Hallo', ' ', 'World', '!', "\n", 'How are you?';
// vs.
echo 'Hallo' . ' ' . 'World' . '!' . "\n" . 'How are you?';
```

The first one copies 5 bytes + 1 byte + 5 bytes + 1 byte + 1 byte + 12 bytes to the output stream, thus copying 25 bytes.
The second one creates a string with 5 bytes, then creates a string with 6 bytes and copies the 5 + 1 bytes into it, then creates a string with 11 bytes and copies the 6 + 5 bytes into it, then creates a string with 12 bytes and copies the 11 + 1 bytes into it, then creates a string with 13 bytes and copies the 12 + 1 bytes into it, then creates a string with 25 bytes and copies the 13 + 12 bytes into it and then eventually copies these 25 bytes to the output buffer. That would be 92 bytes copied and way more memory allocations done.

**But really, you shouldn't care about that. I very much doubt that the bottleneck of your application will be `echo` performance ;)**

But there still is a reason why I use echo with commas instead of concatenation operators: The comma has the lowest of all [operator precedences](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). That way you never have to write parenthesis.

For example this would work:

```
echo 'The script executed in ', microtime(true) - $startTime, ' seconds';
```

Whereas this would not work as expected (and is undefined behavior I think):

```
echo 'The script executed in ' . microtime(true) - $startTime . ' seconds';
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick resporse. I think that every performance boost will be a great help for overloaded servers.

Comment: Just to explain it: The second option is the fastest, because it does not involve string merging. The slowest will be the dynamic string (3rd option), because it has to search for the values first.

Comment: @Ram no, you can't help overloaded servers with it. There are other things to help. You're going absolutely wrong direction

Comment: What other ways except by buying new hardware?

Comment: @Ram **profiling** dude! Measurements! Finding a REAL bottleneck and eliminating it. By tuning database queries, optimizing data mining, tuning server parameters - that's REAL optimization things. But again, it should be based on measurements, not just "what is faster" questions!

Comment: @ram: LOL you are not to freeing an overloaded server changing your echos ;)

Comment: well, sorry for my ignorant statement

Comment: @Ram the performance differences from that are microscopic. If you have server load problems, it might be better to ask a question about those specifically

Comment: Yes. The differences in performance are minimalistic. Unless you happen to output 140 Gig of data per second through such a script and it uses loads of concatenation, there will not be any perceivable difference.

Comment: @Jacco: This is because phpbench.com mustn't be trusted, as the results are convoluted. If you have a look into the code you will see that output buffering was turned on, thus making the comma variant obviously slower. Really, never believe any statistics you haven’t falsified yourself. Holds true for benchmarks too. You can always turn things the other way round ;)

Answer (score 3):

Oh no, this question again.

**None of these perform the best.**

They're all the same.

Moreover, none of these should be used ever.
It should be **template,** that outputs your data, and you have use it's features, not printing values from your business code directly.

And again, there is no speed difference.
No overloaded server will get no help from such "optimization". Not great one, nor even slightest. If you want to help an overloaded server, you have to profile its performance, not doing useless things.

Comment: Good answer to a rather meaningless question.