# Why does Sublime Text 2 wants me to use double quotes when in write PHP?

Tags: php, sublimetext2, quotes

I am very new to PHP and i use Sublime Text 2 as a frontend developer. I almost use PHP inside HTML and i have heard that it is better to use single quotes ('') because it is faster. But when i e.g. write "ech" than sublime gives me the auto-complete option with double quotes, why is that? And how can ich change it to give me single quotes?

[image]

Comment: Simple quotes are faster to read for PhP compiler because it doesn't interprets you variables. For example, you could print your variable `$a` like this : `echo "value of a : $a";`, but with simple quotes you will have to concatenate the variable and the string like this : `echo 'value of a : ' . $a;`. I found the first method faster to write but it doesn't works when trying to reach a data in an array or apply a function to an object..

Comment: I know and i prefer this syntax: `echo 'value of a : ' . $a`. Or is this bad? I think it's better when you mix HTML + PHP.

Comment: read this .... [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5367550/3113793)

Comment: Okay but still I think it's better when you mix HTML + PHP to use " ' " and " . ". For me it's easier.

Comment: `For me it's easier` @HenningFischer, do what feels easy to you

Answer (score 0):

It really does not matter if you use single or double quotes.

You will find there will be no visible speed difference at all, this is just a thing of personal preference.

You will find your self using both single/double quotes anyway at some points.